# Assigning keyboard shortcuts to KDE Dolphin service menus

Tags: kubuntu, shortcut-keys, kde, dolphin

Is there any way I can assign a keyboard shortcut to a custom service menu I've added to Dolphin? The options menu for keyboard assignments does not seem to show any service menu actions, nor have I managed to find a a `.desktop` entry key that would allow me to set a hotkey.

I know that GNOME's Nautilus uses a [hidden accels file](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME/Tips_and_tricks#Hotkey_alternatives) to allow users to set up custom key bindings. Does a similar option exist for Dolphin, perhaps?

Comment: I don't know if you still are using KDE Plasma but ... I too use Service Menus. After selecting a file you want to act on, press the Menu key, release it and then press the accelerator key (assuming that you've enabled show accelerator keys) corresponding to the particular Service Menu. Does that help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**By my knowledge**

It is not possible to start a KDE Service Menu (context menu) with a keyboard shortcut. This is based on:

The Dolphin is using KDE Framework 5 KIO FileItemActions: https://api.kde.org/frameworks/kio/html/classKFileItemActions.html :

> Detailed Description
>
> This class creates and handles the actions for a
>   url (or urls) in a popupmenu.
>
> This includes:
>
> - "open with " actions, but also
> - builtin services like mount/unmount for old-style device desktop files
> - user-defined actions for a .desktop file, defined in the file itself (see the desktop entry
>     standard)
> - servicemenus actions, defined in .desktop files and selected
>     based on the mimetype of the url

Dolphin source files:

- dolphincontextmenu.cpp -> https://cgit.kde.org/dolphin.git/tree/src/dolphincontextmenu.cpp
- dolphincontextmenu.h -> https://cgit.kde.org/dolphin.git/tree/src/dolphincontextmenu.h

Quote:

```
/**
 * @brief Represents the context menu which appears when doing a right
 *        click on an item or the viewport of the file manager.
 *
```

**Sort of workaround with the Dolphin button shortcuts**

The KDE Forums has a topic 'Play All Media Button for Dolphin': https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=223&t=140139 . It shows how to patch the Dolphin sources to add extra buttons to the Dolphin toolbar. The Dolphin buttons can have the keyboard shortcut.

**Wishes/patches**

You could file a wish at the https://bugs.kde.org .

Patches and the review requests can be added to the KDE's instance of Phabricator: https://phabricator.kde.org/ .

Comment: Thanks a lot for investigating this. It's unfortunate to hear that this is not possible as of this point in time, but I will definitely try to submit a feature request soon. I might also give your workaround a try if I find the time.

Comment: I've just submitted a feature request on KDE's bug tracker about this functionality: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=393142. If anyone else is interested in getting this feature added to Dolphin, please do feel free to voice your support!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what distro you use, but this is for Kubuntu (and works for other distros of course):

You can simulate right click with **xdotool** and map it to your custom shortcut (for me Shift-F10).

Here is how.
First, install xdotool utility:

```
sudo apt install xdotool
```

Then add a new shortcut in *Custom Shortcuts*. 
Set *trigger* to whatever (shortcut) you like (for ex. Shift-F10).
Set *action* to:

> xdotool key 135

(135 is keycode of "Menu-key")

Works for Dolphin 17.12.

Answer (score 0):

Use a software called Autokey-gtk --- > its very good!

you can easily make a script like this one, to do exactly what you want.
If you use Window Filter options you can select where the script may be executed.

In KDE.                                                               For example here i made a script to create a new text file in Dolphin or Desktop.

```
winClass = window.get_active_class()
if "dolphin.dolphin" in winClass:
    keyboard.send_key("<menu>")
    keyboard.send_key("c")
    keyboard.send_key("t")
    
elif "plasmashell.plasmashell" in winClass:
    time.sleep(0.2)
    keyboard.send_key("<menu>")
    time.sleep(0.2)
    keyboard.send_key("n")
    time.sleep(0.2)
    keyboard.send_key("t")
```

[image]